# not received notification after initial firebase using FirebaseOptions

Tags: android, firebase

I want to initial firebase programmatically and add user to pre created project with the firebaseoption like this:

```
 FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new 
 FirebaseOptions.Builder().setGcmSenderId(my-senderId)         
.setApplicationId(my-ApplicationId)                  
.setApiKey(my-ApiKey)
 .build();
    firebaseApp = 
 FirebaseApp.initializeApp(ApplicationLoader.applicationContext, 
 firebaseOptions, FCM_APP_NAME);
```

my-applicationid:
[image]

my-senderid:
[image]

I have two questions:

1. I know where can I find my- senderid and my-applicationid, but I can't find my-apikey. Where is this key?
2. After initial, when I send the firebase message I got the below error:

> {"multicast_id":6162528229231898532,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}

**Update:**

I solved both questions.my-appkey is current_key in the google-services.json.

And we should do like this to get reg token:

```
 final FirebaseInstanceId instanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(firebaseApp);
 instanceId.getToken(my-senderId, FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
```

But I got some new problem, after received message I got the error:

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
>           at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:219)